# Is it possible to reference a variable with a string and an int?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, reference, int

Is it possible to reference a variable with a string and an int, like this:

```
    int number1;

    int j = 1;

    @"number%i", j = 3; //Hope this makes sense..
```

The code above gives me warnings and does not work, how could this be done.

I also tried this, but it doesnt work (for quite obvious reasons):

```
    int j = 1;

    NSString *refString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"number%i", j];

    refString = 3;
```

Im really struggling with this, I know how to do it in Javascript, but not in Obj-C, is it possible?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Do you wish to convert an integer to string ? Also, `regString` is of type `NSString*` to which integral constants like `3` cannot be assigned.

Comment: I actually wrote in parentheses right next to the header of the code you are talking about: "but it doesnt work (for quite obvious reasons)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) I call the Poor Man's Array. The better way to do this is to use a proper collection like an array instead of a bunch of variables that are secretly related. Done right, the code with an array will usually be a lot shorter and cleaner too.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will do it with an array, I was initially trying to be super-customizable with a custom "array" set-up, but I realise it would just become messy.

Comment: Or just create a simple class to avoid "array with magic indexes".

Answer (score 1):

From what I can infer you are trying to set/retrieve different variables based on the value of `j`.

You could use a dictionary for this purpose:

```
NSMutableDictionary *numbers = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
int j = 1;
[numbers setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:j]];
```

And then to retrieve:

```
[[numbers objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:j]] intValue];
```

It's a bit verbose, but you could simplify it by creating a small class.

Comment: That would be the same as using an NSArray, it can only hold NS/UI objects.. so that would not really help... thanks anyways