# Call objects by their string name where the strings are built dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, for-loop

For my iOS app, I created a class named Tile which is a subclass of `UIImageView`.

The tiles are displayed in a kind of an array of 6 rows and 5 column.
I previously created 30 instances of my Tile class. These instances are all named this way: `RiCj` where `i` is the row number and `j` is the column number.

I would like to create a for loop where I would apply a specific treatment to each of my tiles (basically, I want to display the tiles where displayTile is an instance method of the class Tile).

I would love to do something like (I know the code below is incorrect):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfRows ; j++) {
  for (int j = 1; j <= numberOfColumns ; j++) {
     [self.RiCj displayTile];
  }
}
```

I don't know how to do a call to my tiles based on their dynamic string title.

Comment: You can do that for *properties* (as described below).  You can't do it for ordinary variables, though.  And using an array is a much better approach than using properties for this purpose.

Comment: See also [Create multiple variables based on an int count](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2231783), [Syntax help: variable as object name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7940809) [Is it possible to reference a variable with a string and an int?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6049175)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can actually access a property of a class dynamically by creating a string naming the property then using [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1) like so:

```
NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R%dC%d", i, j]; 
tile = [self valueForKey:propertyName];
```

But should you? **No, not in this case**. It's a horrible hack when the perfectly nice alternative of making an array (or array of arrays) is available.

Here's what array of array creation and access might look like (by using handy Objective C literals for arrays):

```
NSArray *tiles = @[
                    @[ tile0C0, tile0C1, tile0C2 ],
                    @[ tile1C0, tile1C1, tile1C2 ],
                    @[ tile2C0, tile2C1, tile2C2 ],
                 ];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows ; j++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfColumns ; j++) {
        tile = tiles[j][i];
        // do stuff with tile
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, technically, it is possible - you may use [Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1) like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfRows; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j <= numberOfColumns; j++) {
    NSString* tileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R%dC%d", i, j]; 
    [[self valueForKey:tileName] displayTile];
  }
}
```

But you **should not**. It won't be a clean solution. Array is a more natural choice here.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to access the instances by their variable names dynamically. You can't do that, as your variable name is designed for you, the programmer, and is not available at runtime.

What you can do, however, is to keep a list of your created instances in an array somewhere, and simply iterate over that array when you need to access them.

Alternatively, if you created the 30 tiles as 30 different properties, you *could* use some dynamic code to get them. At that point, however, I would strongly recommend to use the array technique.

Comment: ok, I get it. So I should create an array of tiles. Thank you

Comment: Yes, he can access his propery dynamically, using Key Value Coding. Not that he should, as there are better ways; but he can if he wishes.

Comment: You mean, like I noted in my 3rd paragraph ? The point is, having 30 properties is most likely not a logical design in this case, unless you want to interact with them separately.

Comment: In your first para you say "you're trying to access the instances by their variable names dynamically. You can't do that"

Comment: Keyword : variable name. Not Property name.

Comment: In his example he write "self.RiCj". That's a property. Where does he refer to them as variable? He didn't. You're the one that used that  word.

Comment: Actually, KVC *can* access instance variables directly.

Comment: KVC can access instance variables, but it cannot access local variables, and I thought I understood (as noted at the start of my answer) that he used local variables. Since he's using properties, my 3rd paragraph applies, not the first.