# Simple way to create multiple strings in a with a loop

Tags: objective-c, string, loops

I'm looking for a simple way to create strings with different names in a loop. something like this,

```
nsstring *str1;
nsstring *str2;
nsstring *str3;
```

just with a

```
for loop
```

to create about 100 of them.

Comment: You cannot -- and should not -- do this. If you have a bunch of variables with numbers at the end of their names, you actually should have an array. See also [Create multiple variables based on an int count](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2231783), [Syntax help: variable as object name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7940809), and [Is it possible to reference a variable with a string and an int?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6049175)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray array];
for(int i=1; i<=100; i++){
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"string%d", i]];
}
```

Array now should have 100 strings named like string1, string2, string3...and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately the reason for me asking the question was to avoid that particular way :(

Comment: Also I'm not trying to name the actual string, I want the pointer to the string to be renamed to str1, str2...

Comment: May I ask why you need the pointer to the string to be a specific name?