# Accessing variables with related names in a for loop

Tags: objective-c, variables, for-loop, variable-names

I have three `NSRect`s in separate variables named `rect1`, `rect2`, and `rect3`, and I want to increment each one's `origin.x` by 10.

I thought a for-loop would be good for this, but I don't know how I can do it.

This is an example of how I want it to work:

```
for(int i=0, i<3, i++) {
   rect[i].origin.x +=10
}
```

but this exact code gives an error

> property "rect" not found on object of type "graphics"

Is there a way to code it like in my example?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: It wont accept "rect[i]"

Comment: Be more specific. Define "won't accept". If you are getting a warning or error, post the exact message. Also tell us how `rect` is declared.

Comment: Ok sorry, they are all decleared as NSRect so for example:
NSRect rect1;
NSRect rect2;
The error that it produces is: "property "rect" not found on object of type "graphics"

Comment: If you have only 3 NSRect why the for loop ?

Comment: @user3195648 You can't access individual variables using array syntax.

Comment: rect[i] means the i th number of rect in the array,but apparently you are trying to use it to access rect'i' (the name) variable instead

Comment: yes that's why I ask if there is a way to do it for the variable?

Comment: See also [ObjC equivalent of PHP's "Variable Variables"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283374/objective-c-equivalent-of-phps-variable-variables), [Create multiple variables based on an int count](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2231783), and [Is it possible to reference a variable with a string and an int?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6049175)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to increment a variable with for loop

Not in objective-c for sure. You cannot declare variables in 0-n format and loop through it.

If you create an array out of your `NSRect` variables then you can loop through the array and modify properties.

Note: NSArray can only hold Objects not primitives, you might find [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSValue/valueWithRect:) handy

Comment: so I can put the data in a NSArray and convert the rects to NSValue via valueWithRect:? Am I right?